# Android AVD (Virtual Device) Isn't launching.

Tags: android, eclipse

I've already checked similar posts to this but their solutions don't work.
Here's what I've got:

1. Latest Version of Eclipse. (Kepler Service Release 1)
2. Latest Version of Android SDK, AVD, and ADT Plug-in for Eclipse.
3. It's not a waiting issue.
4. Emulator.exe is never initialized and does not appear in the Task manager
5. The DDMS is left blank and so is LogCat so it's not just taking a long time, it's never starting.
6. There are no errors in eclipse. The error log is cleared, the AVD is "started" and after a moment saying "Starting emulator for AVD" it closes the window and nothing happens. DDMS still blank, LogCat, still blank, and error log, still blank.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it turns out, I didn't have enough space on the C:/ drive for everything to load up. I'm still confused why it never gave any errors or anything but once I deleted stuff like the Recycling Bin and opened up a few Gigs, the emulator started up just fine.
Thanks.